# How to check length of string in subitem in listview VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a list view that contains four columns. I want to check the fourth column and see what the length of string.
note that there are two lines in some rows of this column as shown in the photo below.
each line on these rows shoud be counted separatly. if one line is more than 38 charecters, the row background will change can i do that?
thank you all

[image]

like this:

[image]

this is my cod for listview that contain one column:

```
 For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                ListView1.Items(i).Selected = True
                If ListView1.Items(i).Text.Count > 38 Then
                    ListView1.SelectedItems(i).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(216, 141, 111)
                 
                Else
                End If
            Next i
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service, we need to see what you've written and any errors you're getting.

Comment: @Slugsie No so far i have written a cod for this issue because i do not know how to write it.
of course i wrote a cod for listview contains one colume which works well

Comment: @Slugsie of course by adding a ListView1.Items(i).SubItem(3).Text.Count > 38 recognize the third column but how can <br/> be idebtified to be counted length separately rows in one cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the HTML break tag `<br />` in the fourth column is there as a line break identifier and you want to change the subitem's background color **if** the length of any line is greater than 38, then you can write:

```vb
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    If lvi.SubItems.Count > 2 Then
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
        If lvi.SubItems(3).Text.
            Split({"<br/>", "<br />"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
            Any(Function(line) line.Length > 38) Then
            lvi.SubItems(3).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(216, 141, 111)
        Else
            lvi.SubItems(3).BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If you need instead to change the background color of the `ListViewItem`:

```vb
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    If lvi.SubItems.Count > 2 Then
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = True 'The default.
        If lvi.SubItems(3).Text.
            Split({"<br/>", "<br />"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
            Any(Function(line) line.Length > 38) Then
            lvi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(216, 141, 111)
        Else
            lvi.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: WOW this cod is excellent. this cod works like a charm. thanks a million dear dr.null for help.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Linq code. Sometimes easier to follow. I know Linq is cool but it is not any faster.

```
Private Sub FindLongLines()
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        Dim TurnBrown As Boolean
        Dim lines = itm.SubItems(3).Text.Split({"<br/>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each line In lines
            If line.Length > 38 Then
                TurnBrown = True
                Exit For 'as soon as any line is found longer than 38 further checking is unnessary.
            End If
        Next
        If TurnBrown Then
            itm.SubItems(3).BackColor = Color.Brown
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```